# Как замерить время выполнения функции?

Tags: ассемблер, дизассемблирование, c++

Добрый день!

Есть программа, в ней некая функция. Не важно что за функция.
Проблема в том, какими средствами, как можно замерить время начала вызова этой функции
и ее завершения???
Если были бы исходники - без проблем. А в чистом exe как такое провернуть?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Самый простой (до 1 сек точность) - это использовать функцию `GetTickCount()` пример:

```
unsigned long int tc = GetTickCount();

...//ваша функция

diff = GetTickCount() - tc;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Как замерить время выполнения функции?

думаю, как и большинство профилировщиков: руководствуясь отладочной информацией, подставить в прологе и эпилоге `rdtsc` (или аналоги - `perf. counters`, в интересах `multithreading`) и собрать с них временные метки.

**Обновление**

Что касается `Windows`, то литература известная - [Portable Executable](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). Зная адрес и размер функции, ее можно скопировать в дополнительную секцию, добавить нужные команды и подменить адреса вызова (references) по коду.
 --
[Microsoft PE and COFF Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx)
 --
Правда, в некоторых случаях, когда есть какая-то зависимость от содержимого функции, такая схема скорее всего обрушит приложение (инкапсулированные упаковщики, шифровальщики и т.п.)

Comment: Я далеко не профессионал в ассемблере, можете подсобить литературой? Примером может каким? Представления не имею куда подставить( Есть метод, начинается допустим с push в стек переменных... в winhex push имеет там какой-то код... Но после него идут инструкции какие-то... перетирать их нельзя. А можно его как-то вклинить? Не плохо было бы на примере посмотреть) Спасибо)

Comment: @mega, не обязательно саму функцию копировать, можно сделать функцию-"переходник", вызываемую вместо целевой функции, которая уже вызывает нужную функцию и замеряет время ее выполнения.